# Análise Fatorial, Transformar uma Variável de Escala Likert em Contínua, R

Tags: r

Estou com dificuldade em transformar uma variável "Patido", em Escala Likert, para uma variável contínua, através de análise fatorial. Alguém poderia me ajudar com o código?

A base de dados que eu estou utilizando é a o painel da ANES (2008-2009) que possui informações sobre as eleições americanas.

Já filtrei a base de dados e ela se encontra neste formato long:

```
# A tibble: 25,440 × 15
   caseid der01  der02 der03  der04 der05 der06 der10a der16 der20 der22 der24 Wave  Patido
    <dbl> <fct>  <dbl> <fct>  <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct>  <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> 
 1      8 Mulher    73 Não H… Bran… NA    NA    NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    Wave… NA    
 2      8 Mulher    73 Não H… Bran… NA    NA    NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    Wave… NA    
 3      8 Mulher    73 Não H… Bran… NA    NA    NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    Wave… NA    
 4      8 Mulher    73 Não H… Bran… NA    NA    NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    Wave… NA    
 5      8 Mulher    73 Não H… Bran… NA    NA    NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    Wave… NA    
 6      8 Mulher    73 Não H… Bran… NA    NA    NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    Wave… NA    
 7     12 Mulher    35 Não H… Bran… Bach… $125… Votou  Bara… John… NA    Marr… Wave… NA    
 8     12 Mulher    35 Não H… Bran… Bach… $125… Votou  Bara… John… NA    Marr… Wave… Indep…
 9     12 Mulher    35 Não H… Bran… Bach… $125… Votou  Bara… John… NA    Marr… Wave… Indep…
10     12 Mulher    35 Não H… Bran… Bach… $125… Votou  Bara… John… NA    Marr… Wave… Indep…
# … with 25,430 more rows, and 1 more variable: Valores <fct>
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows, and `colnames()` to see all variable names
```

Em que:

**caseid**: ID do indivíduo  (em que estou indexando)
**Wave**: Tempo (em que estou indexando)
**Patido**: variável em escala linkertg que quero transformar em contínua por análise fatorial

A escala da variável patido é a seguinte:
"Strong Democrat",
"Not very strong Democrat",
"Independent-Democrat",
"Independent-Independent",
Independent-Republican",
"Not very strong Republican",
"Strong Republican"

Tentei a função factanal(), porém deu erro.

Comment: Eu não consigo ver como essa pergunta é fora do escopo do site... Enfim, `Patido` está salvo como uma variável fator, se o níveis dela estiverem na ordem certa basta utilizar `unclass(Patido)` ou `as.numeric(Partido)` para transforma-la em uma variável númerica. Ajudaria também se você colocasse o erro que `factanal()`está retornando